# How do I share a a resource DLL containing icons between Windows 7 and XP?

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, embedded-resource

I've got a project that has some icons, bitmaps, and strings embedded in resource DLLs for the purpose of MUI. These all work perfectly fine in Windows 7, but only the strings and bitmaps work in XP. I'm building the app on Windows 7 using VS2012, using Visual Studio 2010 (v100) as the actual toolset.

As MUI is not natively supported on XP I programmatically acquire a handle to the appropriate resource DLL based on steps 5.1c and 5.2 of [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee845043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#step_5).

The result of GetLastError after I try LoadImage for my icon from my resource on XP is 1813, or ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND. Calling LoadImage for a bitmap or LoadString on the same resource handle works correctly, and indeed, my strings and bitmaps appear where appropriate.

Something I've noticed: if I try to set the icon for a shortcut by opening my application's DLL Windows 7 has no problem, but Windows XP reports that the file contains no icons. XP has no problem loading the ico files themselves if I copy them over, so I don't think they're in a bad format, unless the resource compiler is mangling them in some way. If I look at the icon in the resource editor it appears as a 16x16 32-bit BMP file, as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was caused by VS2012 somehow. I'm not sure what the difference is between building resource DLLs in VS2010 with VS2010 tools and building them in VS2012 with VS2010 tools, but there is one.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an MUI solution your resources are split between a language-neutral DLL (which usually contains icons, manifests, etc.) and language-specific DLLs (which usually contain strings, dialogs, etc.)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee845043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#platform_requirements): "The pre-Windows Vista resource loading functions (such as LoadString, LoadIcon, LoadBitmap, FormatMessage, and others) are non-MUI aware."

Your strings and icons may not be in the same DLL, and XP won't go looking for them.  The article I linked to explains how to make MUI work on Windows XP.

Comment: They're not MUI aware, but if you pass them a handle to a language-specific DLL they still work (I'll update the question with more info about how I get that handle). I have verified that this works when it comes to strings and bitmaps. It's only the icons (all of which are set to be locale-specific) that don't show up. I have verified that other than a MUI and manifest sections, there are no resources in the language-neutral DLL or the main exe, so my locale-specific DLL is being loaded, but there's something about the icons section that's not right.

Comment: @MilesStrombach: Fair enough.  How are the icons encoded?  Windows Vista introduced support for icons that contain PNG encoded data.  You say the icon files work on XP, but maybe the resource compiler is compressing them into PNG?  Does the resource editor tell you what format the icons in the DLL are in?  If not, open the DLL in the resource editor, save an icon as a .ico, open it in notepad and see if it contains the letters "PNG".

Comment: I used a couple different resource extractors and all of the icons they pull out look like 32-bit BMPs and lack the PNG header.